# Does "Toggle Comment" shortcut work for Android development in Netbeans 7.2?

Tags: android, netbeans, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans-7.2

Frustratingly, my Ctrl+/ keyboard shortcut doesn't comment out a line of code when a .java file is open in the Netbeans 7.2 code editor. The "Toggle Comment" entry on the Source menu doesn't show any assigned shortcut, but the shortcut is specified in Tools >> Options >> Keymap and it works fine for other languages.

Does anybody else have this issue and have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me in NBAndroid project. Sounds like a NetBeans bug or some weirdness in your setup to me. A quick question: is it NBAndroid project or Maven? Though it should work in both.

-Radim

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's NBAndroid at http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/download/updatecenter/updates.xml

Comment: This is the correct answer. It confirms that my system is broken and that I need not file a Netbeans bug.